# Azure server not responding but dashboard reporting everything is running?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Very suddenly without any changes or recent access my Azure virtual server is no longer available for RDP or web...I have logged into the azure control panel and everything appears to running without issue but it is not working.

I have checked the end points and they are present for both RDP and Web, totally weird.

I have 2 virtual servers and the other one is working fine and responding.

Anyone ever experience this? Just when my client wants to view his website as well...

http://cn-web-02.cloudapp.net is the URL

TIA

Comment: So far tried rebooting...removing the web endpoint and adding again..no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As I just answered for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286175/272109), Virtual Machines are in *Preview* and not in Production yet. There are several reasons why your Virtual Machines became unavailable (see other answer). Given that this is the second reported incident here today, it's a good guess it's related to the underlying Host OS being updated, which would take your Virtual Machine offline for a short period of time.

I tried your URL and it's available again. Just remember about this being in Preview, especially since you mention having a client that wants to view his website. If you put a production website in Virtual Machines, then you'll have to absorb the risk of not having an SLA.

Having said *that*: You can mitigate downtime risk by running two Virtual Machines, listening on a load-balanced input endpoint. Be sure to have both Virtual Machines in the same Availability Set. Doing that ensures that the Windows Azure fabric controller will not take both Virtual Machines offline at the same time when doing things like Host OS updates. If this were in Production, you'd then have a very high availability scenario. Even in Preview, you'll improve availability by taking advantage of Availability Sets.  Note: You'll need to use some type of shared session cache, since visitors will now be sent to either one of your Virtual Machines.

Comment: Thanks for those comments David...I'm guessing you have the two servers in different locations? I feel 22 hours is a very long time for OS updates etc.

Comment: Regarding 22-hour window: If there's some type of outage, that's very different from updates. And I can't really speak to that, aside from public statements, as a Microsoft employee (sorry...). As for different locations: Availability Sets are in the same data center, but separated physically (e.g. different racks), as well as logically (e.g. updated separately).

Comment: No worries David...appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

I had same experience on it! We had 2 instances and all of its were re-imaged without any notified. I known it since we made some local change via RDP.

Reboot or Reimage may help! You may try!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an outage from Microsoft...for over 22 hours but everything is back up and running. This is the 2nd time in 6 months this has happened for long stretches...makes me a little nervous to say the least.

Thanks for the input everyone and for anyone that's interested MS have a good site that tracks the service levels on Azure. [Windows Azure Service Dashboard](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/)

S